# document.querySelector argumentos

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente código de ejemplo:

```js
ul = document.getElementById("list");
li = document.querySelector("#list li");
cuerpo = document.body;

ul.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  console.log("Clicked on ul");
});

li.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  console.log("Clicked on li");
});
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Que lo estoy utilizando para entender el proceso de Propagación de Eventos. Como por default es bubbling, debería mostrar el mensaje de console.log("Clicked on li"); y luego el de ul. Pero no lo hace, solo muestra el de ul.

Si hago lo mismo con otros elementos HTML, la propagación funciona correctamente. Por lo que para mí el problema esta en el argumento de  document.querySelector. Se me hizo muy compleja la información de MDN o de la propia W3C. Así que agradecería si me pudiesen decir si `"#list li"` es un argumento válido y sino, de que manera podría lograr lo que me propongo.

EDIT: Me he dado cuenta que solo el primer li responde al evento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que el `querySelector` te va a devolver un solo objeto, para hacer lo que quieres debes usar [**`querySelectorAll`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) que devuelve un *arreglo* con todos los objetos `li`, dentro de `#list`, luego deberías recorrerlos con un ciclo `for` y asignarles un `listener` a cada uno, es decir, deberías cambiar tu código a este:

```js
var ul = document.getElementById("list");
var li = document.querySelectorAll("#list li");
var cuerpo = document.body;

ul.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  console.log("Clicked on ul");
});

for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  li[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    console.log("Clicked on li");
  });
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto ocurre por que `document.querySelector` solo retorna el primer elemento que coincida con el selector especificado. Para obtener todos los `li` dentro de `ul` deberias usar `document.querySelectorAll` que devuelve un nodeList de elementos, entonces ese nodeList se recorre con un `forEach` y a cada `li` le asignamos un listener.

```js
var ul = document.getElementById("list");
var li = document.querySelectorAll("#list li");
var cuerpo = document.body;

ul.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  console.log("Clicked on ul");
});

Array.prototype.forEach.call(li, function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    console.log('Clicked on li');
   });
});
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Con `querySelector()` se obtiene el primer elemento de una clase dada, según puedo entender quieres todos los elementos de la clase, para eso debes usar `querySelectorAll()`.

Ejemplo:

```js
ul = document.getElementById("list");
li = document.querySelectorAll("#list li"); // Todos los Elementos
cuerpo = document.body;

ul.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  console.log("Clicked on ul");
});

for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  li.item(i).addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    console.log("Clicked on li");
  });
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Si deseas que el evento onClick no se propague de hijo a padre, puedes detenerlo con el método event.stopPropagation().

Ejemplo:

```js
ul = document.getElementById("list");
li = document.querySelectorAll("#list li"); // Todos los Elementos
cuerpo = document.body;

ul.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  console.log("Clicked on ul");
});

for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  li.item(i).addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    console.log("Clicked on li");
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```